# okhttp3 - SSLHandshakeException Handshake failed on Android 5

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

```
javax.net.ssl.: Handshake failed
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xddf5a200: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1407743E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert inappropriate fallback (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:765 0xeba8fce0:0x00000000)
```

Comment: Does Jesse's workaround in this Github issue work? It's for okhttp2 so I'm not adding it as an answer for now. https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1582#issuecomment-95979104

Comment: removing `s` from `https` worked for me.